# How to call some method repeatedly by holding down the UIButton in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios5, uibutton, xcode4.3

I need to call some method repeatedly by holding down the UIButton. Once i released the Button it should stop calling that method. how can i implement this functionality do anyone having idea about this means please help me to get out of this issue..Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Try using `UIControlEventTouchDown`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `touchesBegan` method to call this method and `touchesEnd` to stop this method.

Inside the method you can use some loop- `for` or `while` to call this method depending on condition, or you can start a timer to call this method in `touchesBegan` and invalidate the timer in `touchesEnd`.